# Moving cells once a checkbox is TRUE but also other conditions are met

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am really new to scripting -to the point that I have messed that much I don't even have a script or attempt script to upload as a sample.

I will try explain - I have 2 sheets, Source Sheet & Destination Sheet.

When checkbox in column E is TRUE, I want to check if COLUMN A & C are not EMPTY on that same row that the checkbox is edited.If these conditions are true, then copy that row to the DESTINATION SHEET.

I've tried researching and piecing together different things I have searched but just cannot get this to work.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow - https://stackoverflow.com/tour!

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container bound apps script within the spreadsheet and write the below function there. When you run this function, it will copy the rows if checkbox column E is true and column A & C also have data.

```
    function copyRowsWithCheckboxTrue() {
      var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
      var sourceSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Source");
      var destinationSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("Destination");
      
      var data = sourceSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
      var destinationData = [];
      
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var checkboxValue = data[i][4]; // Assuming checkbox is in column E (index 4)
        var valueA = data[i][0]; // Value in column A
        var valueC = data[i][2]; // Value in column C
        
        if (checkboxValue === true && valueA !== "" && valueC !== "") {
          destinationData.push(data[i]);
        }
      }
      
      if (destinationData.length > 0) {
        destinationSheet.getRange(destinationSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, destinationData.length, destinationData[0].length).setValues(destinationData);
        console.log("Rows copied to destination sheet.");
      } else {
        console.log("No rows to copy.");
      }
    }
```

Please try this and let me know if any issues. I've tried this and it worked. For reference - [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Dvoa1IGXFYCuWSuwoLDOvyyqxGNc2qp3C9P4V0uErzs/edit)